# Chrome extension : sending submit from background.html

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I`m making chrome extension and have  problem with submitting from background.html

For example this works:

```
var url="some url";

chrome.tabs.create({"url":url, selected:true});
```

but if i`ll try to do:

```
document.forms["test"].submit();
```

It works only once when I just installed extension or after reboot

**UPDATE**

I am trying to submit this form which is in background.html:

```
<FORM action="some url" name="test" id = "test" method="post" target="_blank" > 
    <input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="12" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="addr" name="addr" value="" /> 
</form>
```

then i create menu

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "test", "parentId": parentID, "contexts":["selection"], "onclick": SubmitFunction}); 

SubmitFunction(){ 
    document.forms["test"].submit();
}
```

It works only one time after rebooting or after installation

Comment: When do you expect it to work?

Comment: I trying to submit this form  which is in background.html
 <FORM action="some url" name="test" id = "test"  method="post" target="_blank" >
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="12" />
<input type="hidden" id="addr" name="addr" value="" />
</form> 
  then  i create   menu    
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "test", "parentId": parentID, "contexts":["selection"], "onclick": SubmitFunction});
 SubmitFunction(){  document.forms["test"].submit();}
 It works only one time after rebooting or after installation

Comment: Basically I want to send post request to server from background.html

Answer (score 1):

background.html exists in the extension context and can not directly alter pages b/c pages exist within their own page context. In your case background.html has no context for any particular page/tab when you call submit(). So you will probably need to use a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and then communicate with it via [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: Thank you for help i will  look more in to content script . background.html has some content  <FORM action="some url" name="test" id = "test" method="post" target="_blank" > <input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="12" /> <input type="hidden" id="addr" name="addr" value="" /> </form>

Comment: I see. It may not be valid to have forms inside the background page. YOu might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a POST request to a web server you should use `XMLHttpRequest`. If you know jQuery or any other framework, they usually provide convenient wrappers for this:

```
$.post("some_url", { test: "...", addr: "..." }); //jQuery
```

If not, then you can use `XMLHttpRequest` directly:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        console.log("done");
    }
}
xhr.open("POST","some_url",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("test=TEST_VALUE&addr=ADDRESS_VALUE");
```

More details [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html).

Comment: Thank you.Looks like what I need. Is  there any way in $.post or XMLHttpRequest to open in new tab something like target="_blank" for form.

Comment: @user766182 I don't think so. Here is similar problem to what you described, looks like it is a bug in Chrome (no solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024240/submit-a-form-to-a-new-tab-more-than-once

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while developing my chrome extension. My background page had a form with a _blank target. It would only open the new window once, but if I tried to submit it again it quietly did nothing. I don't know why this happens, but here is my solution.

```
function randomString(){
    return ((Math.PI * Math.max(0.01, Math.random())).toString(36).substr(2, 5));
} 

function submitMyForm(){
   ... //do whatever form preparations here
   var rn = randomString();
   $('#myForm')[0].target = rn;
   window.open('', rn);
   $('#myForm').submit();
}
```

Basically I changed the target to a random name and it just worked after that. Why? I don't know, maybe someone else can clairify that, but his works for me.

(I'm also using JQuery,but if you need vanilla JavaScript just replace with "document.getElementById('myForm')" where needed)